# Can someone tell me why my $.ajax call isn't returning the array from my PHP page?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've been trying to figure this out all day and I'm hitting a brick wall (with my head).

I've got this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Construct Films - Interface</title>
    <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var oXHR; 
        $("#timeSel").submit(function(event){
            if (oXHR){
                oXHR.abort();
            }
            var $form = $(this);
            var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
            var serializedData = $form.serialize();
            $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
            var iDate = $("input#imageDate").val();
               oXHR = $.ajax({
                    url: "fetch_images.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: serializedData
                });
            oXHR.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                // log a message to the console
                $("#output").text(response);
                console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
                });
            oXHR.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                // log the error to the console
                console.error("The following error occured: "+textStatus, errorThrown);
                });
            oXHR.always(function () {
                // reenable the inputs
                $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
                });
        event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='usrSelection'>
        <form id="timeSel">
            Select date: <input id="imageDate" name="imageDate" type="date">
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
    <div id='output'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my PHP:

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    $username  = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $imageDate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['iDate']);
    $result = mysql_query("
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            images AS i
        INNER JOIN
            users AS u ON i.userID = u.UserID
        WHERE
            u.username = '$username'
        AND 
            i.imageDate = '$imageDate'
        ORDER BY
        imageTime
        ASC
    ") or die(mysql_error());
    // populate the imageSelector div with a time selector
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        echo $row['imageTime'];
        //echo "<option>" . $row['imageTime'] . "</option>";
    }
?>
```

I'm getting the message in the console "Hooray, it worked!" but I'm not getting any actual data back from the MySQL query, or an SQL error... I'm new to AJAX and trying to figure out why this isn't working. 
if I change the php page to some thing like

```
<?php
echo "some stuff";
>
```

then I get that returned to the output div no problems.
Thanks for any help.
Graham

Comment: If you get the later string i.e `"some stuff"`, this means your query doesn't return any rows. Check your query first if it returns any rows

Comment: I don't know what `connect.php` includes exactly, but I would assume that it only generates a database connection. So my guess is that `$username` is undefined.

Comment: `$username  = mysql_real_escape_string($username);`  Where is `$username` being set originally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query isnt returning any results, probably because of the following:

```
$imageDate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['iDate']);
```

Should  be

```
$imageDate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imageDate']);
```

as there is no iDate form input.

Also, `$username` does not appear to be set anywhere.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who pointed out the $username wasn't set. I've included '$username = $_COOKIE['visit'];' and the 'imageDate' change and now all is fine. Phew!